# Nginx cluster is not being created hence rate limits are not being shared

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting

Nginx cluster is not being created, hence rate-limits are not being shared between nginx instances.

"api/stream/zone_sync" returns node="0"

I have use limit_req_zone with sync parameter and provided cluster configuration using zone_sync_server, please find the configuration details

instance1 nginx.conf PI address A.B.C.D

http {

```
server {
   listen 8000

   limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:1m rate=4r/m sync;

   location /test {
        limit_req zone=mylimit burst=4 nodelay;
   }
}
```

}
stream {

```
server {
    zone_sync;
    listen A.B.C.D:9000
    zone_sync_server X.Y.Z.W:9000
}
```

}
instance2 nginx.conf running on pi address X.Y.Z.W

http {

```
server {
   listen 8000

   limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:1m rate=4r/m sync;

   location /test {
        limit_req zone=mylimit burst=4 nodelay;
   }
}
```

}
stream {

```
server {
    zone_sync;
    listen X.Y.Z.W:9000
    zone_sync_server A.B.C.D:9000
}
```

}
Nginx version is - nginx version: nginx/1.15.10 (nginx-plus-r18-p1)

Both instance serves 4 request in a min got /test api end point, my exception is in total both serve 4 in a min.

Can you please suggest what is missing here?